# Определение ширины элемента за пределами максимального

Tags: html, css, width

Как определить, какой элемент вылетает за пределы максимальной ширины (окна)?
Понимаю, нужно было изначально писать правильно, но это мой первый сайт, так что не судите строго.
Постскриптум: при изменении окна браузера к минимуму появляется периодически горизонтальный скроллинг, о чем и заявляет, что где-то вылезает блок за пределы.
Сам сайт: dsz.zzz.com.ua

Comment: Aww yeah, адаптивная верстка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В браузерах, в контекстном меню есть пункт `Просмотреть код элемента` (в `Opera` (для остальных название может отличаться)). Через него проще всего найти проблемы в разметке.

В вашем случае проблему создают боксы `Информация` и `Полезные ссылки`, а именно свойства `min-width` и `margin`. Если их отключить, это решит данную проблему. Но отключение вызовет смещение текста во втором боксе. Не дело! Поэкспериментировав я нашёл следующее решение: У `.wrapperInf` изменить `width` на **36%**. После чего у `@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)` в скобках изменить `max-width` с **480px** на **500px** (тут можно указать и другие значения. Чем выше `max-width` у `@media only screen and`, тем больше можно брать `width` у `.wrapperInf` (например, для **550px** у `@media`, `width` у `.wrapperInf`, не вызывающий смещения будет **41%**)). Это почти решит проблему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему же почти? Потому что есть ещё один блок, который продолжает вызывать смещение в небольшой промежуток уменьшения сайта. Это картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исправить это смещение можно 3 способами:

1) Изменив свойство `width` у `.wrapperImgFB` на **95%**.

2) Удалив свойство `width` у `.wrapperImgFB` **(лучший вариант!)**.

3) Удалив свойство `margin` у `.wrapperImgFB`.

> **UPD:**

Ещё одну проблему заметил при уменьшении окна браузера до минимального размера происходит небольшое смещение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вылечить можно изменением у `.headInf` свойства `width` с **80%** на **79%**.

Comment: Спасибо, что указал, в чем проблема. Смотрел я до этого через код элемента, но так и не нашел ничего, даже переделывал стили, несколько часов все равно сошлись в пустую.

Comment: Чтобы точно понять, где происходит смещение, нужно раскрыть весь каталог сайта в просмотре кода, поймать момент, на котором происходит смещение, передвинуть нижний скролл в крайнее правое положение и идти с проверкой по каждому элементу. С помощью подсветки элементов вы без проблем увидите, какой элемент не помещается на странице. Самое удобное, это то, что прямо в просмотре кода вы можете менять, отключать или добавлять свойства и смотреть, что при этом происходит.